# How to add the check box and button in jquery data table column

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, datatables

I need to add the check box and button in jquery data table all rows. check box need to add the first column and button need to add the final column. using mvc format. I try this below code . but its only display the button only. How can i add the check box in very first column

Comment: checkboxes in html are usually part of input elements: <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="val"> Option

Comment: I try that bu not use. in same i try to the same button its also not response

Answer (score 1):

Using like this:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [{
                "aTargets": [0],
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    if (iCol == 0) {
                       $('<input type=\"checkbox\" value="' + sData + '">');
                    }
                }
            },
            {
            "aTargets": [7],
                "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                    if (iCol == 7) {
                        var b = $('<button>test</button>');
                        b.on('click', function () {
                        });
                        $(nTd).empty();
                        $(nTd).prepend(b);
                    }
                }
            }],
```